# AngularJS - Execute function in controller for last using $timeout()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the main controller I wrote:

```
angular.element(window).load(function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        scrollAnchor(); // Scroll to Anchor
    });
});
```

I'd this to to scroll to the last operation right after all elements were rendered. The problem is that there are also other `$timeout()` with other functions. So the scrolling is not the last operation. Is there a way to introduce a priority over the functions executed in `$timeout`?

Comment: Please add the other operations using `$timeout`. So we can deliver you a nice and stable solution. I promise, in the end you dont need even one `$timeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't supply a *delay* parameter, the function is called on the next digest cycle.

So, to make sure that certain delayed executions are performed *after* others with the same parameters, just set a higher delay.

```
$timeout(scrollAnchor, 500);
```

Or you could fire an event when you know that "everything else" is done and then scroll to where you want to scroll.

Comment: He said, there are other timeouts. In that way your solution is not stable/clean. You need to ensure that all other render operations are finished. Working with delays is such a problem in JavaScript because it is much depending on the client performance. This could break your application.

Comment: @lin, you are right, its not a good solution to use 500 milliseconds for me. The problem is that were used other $timeout, and I don't know when they finish their execution.

Comment: @Labo29, just add the "other operations code" into your question. We will find a solution.

Comment: The delay is exactly what was being asked for in that it priorities the start of execution. If something needs to be delayed until the end of execution, see the second part of my answer.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg ok, if using delays is the only way, I will search for another solution which doesn't use $timeout. I don't like to put delays in page, they are too unreliable.

Comment: Well, it's not the only solution. If you control all the other animations, have them fire an event when they are complete, as I suggested. Angular itself doesn't really know when "everything is complete", you have to control it yourself. You can do a "best guess" approach with the delays or go with a more complex approach where you keep track of everything during page load.

Comment: @Labo29 we will find a solution for you if you add some more code.

Comment: @lin I founded the problem. I am working on code not written by me, and I found several $timeout with delay 4000 500 and 2000. That is the problem. I have to modify the code to remove all these $timeout.